# How to write into a txt file with TASM

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

So, openning file and closing file works perfectly, it works with the read file as its suppose to be,
now, I am trying to update numbers inside the txt file by dismanteling the numbers and converting them to their ascii codes, after I did that, putting them into use to be written, seems to be editing nothing in my txt file, what happend?

```
coins db 31
coinsArray db 3 dup (0)
coinsLeng dw ?
buffer db 256 dup (0)

proc WriteToFileCoins
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, [fileHandle]
    call SetCoinsInBuffer ;Setting the numbers to appear in the buffer
    mov cx, [coinsLeng] ;Length to be used
    inc cx ;Since the length is counted 0 && 1 but interrupt reads till 0
    mov dx, offset buffer
    int 21h
    call CloseFile
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret
endp WriteToFileCoins

proc SetCoinsInBuffer
push ax
push di
push bx
push cx
push si
    xor ax, ax
    mov di, 0
    mov bl, 10d
    mov al, [coins]
ASC2:
        xor ah, ah
        div bl             ; ax/bl
        mov ch, ah         ; Asci number starts at 48, saving and adding.
        add ch, 48d
        mov [coinsArray+di], ch           ; Saves in array
        cmp al, 0d
        je CoinsSet             ;IF AX=0, END OF THE PROCEDURE
        inc di
        jmp asc2
CoinsSet:
    mov [coinsLeng], di ; I saved them reversed in the 'coinarray'
    xor si, si
CoinsReSet:
    xor bx, bx
    mov bl, [coinsArray+di]
    mov [buffer+si], bl
    cmp di, 0
    je FinishedSettingBuffer
    dec di
    inc si
    jmp CoinsReSet
FinishedSettingBuffer:
pop si
pop cx
pop bx
pop di
pop ax
ret
EndP SetCoinsInBuffer
```

Comment: are you sure you really open the file for writing ? use `mov ax,3d02h  int 21h` to open it, then you can write into it

Comment: Hey, I did set AL (access code) to 2, which should be read/write but I didn't do mov ax, 3d02h, my open file is https://pastebin.com/ctPnHyS7

Comment: you wrote    `mov ah,3D` `xor al,al` `mov al, 2` which will also result in a value of AX=3d02, so the problem isn't the fopen()

Comment: I'd try to write a simple `"hello world",0ah, 0dh` buffer, just to see if the fwrite() is the problem, or if it's somewhere else ( and  a debugger could really help :) )

Comment: the code shown works like a charm, I just had one problem: my assembler assembles `cmp al, 0d` into `cmp al, 0x0d` and not `cmp al,0x00` like you want it there, but I think TASM wont, you'd otherwise get an endless loop there

Comment: Thank you very, very much, works! mov ax, 3d02h